# How to solve flutter configuration conflict?

Tags: android, flutter

When I first joined an organization as a junior flutter developer, I got a notification on some .dart files that in some cases, the code being used needed some changes, which were later reversed by another developer since they could not really work on his computer. For instance:

```dart
 var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
```

In this case I have to add the android and iOS tags for it to work on my ide, but for his it works just fine. Does anyone how I can avoid these configuration conflicts, a possible work around?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the error we are getting is because we are using different versions of `flutter_local_notifications` . Though the version had not been specified explicitly, I tried using a lower version like ^1.0.1+2 down from the available stable version and it works just fine, requiring no tags.